# Relational Learning: What does this Prolog Output say?

Tags: prolog, output

I need to find relations in a prolog dataset. I have different kinds of trains with different features, for example Train1:

```
has_car(rel_east1,car_11).
has_car(rel_east1,car_12).
has_car(rel_east1,car_13).

infront(car_11,car_12).
infront(car_12,car_13).

size(car_11,long).
size(car_12,long).
size(car_13,short).

shape(car_11,hexagon).
shape(car_12,rectangle).
shape(car_13,hexagon).

load(car_11,rectangle).
load(car_12,circle).
load(car_13,triangle).
```

I have ten different trains. Now I used the Metagol algorithm which shall learn the different relations within the different trains. As a result I get a list with different clauses. And here is my problem: I don't understand the inductive steps in between the clauses. For example:

```
relational(A):-has_car(A,B),relational_1(B).
relational_1(A):-relational_2(A,rectangle).
relational_2(A,B):-relational_3(A),shape(A,B).
relational_3(A):-infront(A,B),relational_4(B).
relational_4(A):-load(A,triangle).
```

The only thing I know is, that the whole clause says: "There is a Train which contains a car which is in the shape rectangle. This car is in front of another car which contains a triangle."
But can anybody explain the code to me? Line for line?
For example, I don't understand how to read the 2nd line: "If there is a relation 1 with A, then there is also a relation 2 between A and rectangle"?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but I think the relational_x predicates, are relations (predicates) that are 'invented' by metagol for your learning task.
As naming invented predicates is a hard task (for which there is not a good solution for ) you get these type of names.

For instance if you used the example `kinship1' here : https://github.com/metagol/metagol

```
?- [kinship1].
Warning: /media/sam/9bb6ab40-5f17-481e-aba8-7bd9e4e05d66/home/sam/Documents/Prolog_practise/metagol/metagol.pl:250:
    Local definition of metagol:list_to_set/2 overrides weak import from lists
true.

    ?- a.
    % learning grandparent/2
    % clauses: 1
    % clauses: 2
    % clauses: 3
    grandparent_1(A,B):-father(A,B).
    grandparent_1(A,B):-mother(A,B).
    grandparent(A,B):-grandparent_1(A,C),grandparent_1(C,B).
    true .
```

It learns the `grandparent/2` relation by also learning `grandparent_1/2`. Which we as humans would call `parent/2`.

So `relational_4(A):-load(A,triangle).` you might call 'car carrying a load which is triangle shaped' . and `relational_3(A):-infront(A,B),relational_4(B).` would then be 'car in front of a car carrying a load which is triangle shaped' etc

```
relational_4(A):-load(A,triangle).
```

If an object A is loaded with a triangle then A is relational_4
or 
There is a car which has a load which is a triangle.

```
relational_3(A):-infront(A,B),relational_4(B).
```

If an object A is infront of object B and B is relational_4 then A is relational_3
or
Car A is infront of a car B which has a load which is a triangle

```
relational_2(A,B):-relational_3(A),shape(A,B).
```

If A is relational_3 and has shape B then A relational_2 B.
or
Car A is a car infront of another car which is loaded with a triangle, car A has an unspecified shape.

```
relational_1(A):-relational_2(A,rectangle).
```

If an object A is relational_2 rectangle then A is relational_1
or
There is a car which has a rectangle shape, it is infront of a car which caries a triangle load.

```
relational(A):-has_car(A,B),relational_1(B).
```

If an object A has a car B and B is relational_1 then relational A.

There is a train which has a car, that car is a rectangle in shape and it is infront of a car that has a triangle load